# Adblock detecting script not working, ads.js is being loaded

Tags: javascript, adblock

I have implemented adblock detector described at https://www.detectadblock.com/

For some reason the adblock seem to load my ads.js , first it did not, the code below is located at end of page.
  Is adblock plus somehow learning to load the ads.js file?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ads.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if(!document.getElementById('vjsDVfQJm')){
      document.getElementById('DaxTlcKHYRZ').style.display='block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('DaxTlcKHYRZ').style.display='none';
    }
</script>
```

Content of ads.js

```
ads.js
var e=document.createElement('div');
e.id='vjsDVfQJm';
e.style.display='none';
document.body.appendChild(e);
```

Comment: answered myself already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

code seem to work if ads.js is renamed to adsbygoogle.js

Comment: Having the same issue myself today. Renaming to adsbygoogle.js has not worked for me.